# MySQL Join with Highest?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one called items and one called bids. Bids contains a bunch of bids with an item_id. I am trying to get all the information on the item with the associated highest bid.

I tried doing something like

```
SELECT * FROM items JOIN bids ON items.id=bids.item_id GROUP BY item_id
```

However that seems to return the first bid, not the highest.

How could I get the highest?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and your expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a subquery to discover the maximum bid value, then join that with your existing query to obtain all of the desired output data.  Assuming that the bid value is in a column called `value`, and that the PK of the `bids` table is a column called `id`:

```
SELECT items.*, bids.*
FROM
  items
  JOIN (
    SELECT id, item_id, MAX(value) AS value FROM bids GROUP BY item_id
  ) AS maxbids ON items.id = maxbids.item_id
  JOIN bids    ON  bids.id = maxbids.id
GROUP BY items.id
```

If there are multiple bids of the maximum amount, this query will return all of them.

Answer (score 0):

A self-join will also do it, I think.  So, assuming (as [@eggyal did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401881/mysql-join-with-highest#99667)) that there's a `bids.value` column:

```
SELECT *
FROM items i
  JOIN bids b1 ON b1.item_id=i.id
  JOIN bids b2 ON b2.item_id=i.id AND b2.value>b1.value
WHERE b2.id IS NULL
```

But that will return multiple rows if there are mutiple bids for the same amount.  How do you want to handle them?

(And that `SELECT *` should be narrowed down.)